# what exacly is (function()).()

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm a beginner in programming and I just wonder about one thing. To be exact the syntax of `(function(){...}).()`

This question has been probably asked but as I don't know what it is and how to call it, I had very small luck finding anything about this topic.

I have been checking some scripts lately and I noticed that in some of them people use:

```
(function(){
   ...
}).(something) //
```

So far I'm guessing it's something like function which calls itself right away? How do we use it and what are the advantages of this. What do I put inside where 'something' is? also sometimes before it starts it also has `$` sign.

Comment: IIFE: `(function(){}());`, jQuery ready: `$(function(){});`

Comment: It's normally encountered as shorthand for the jQuery ready() event http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Is there a dot between the close and open parens?  `(function(){...}).()` or `(function(){...})()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a normal function:

```
function foo(){
    ...
}
```

Now let's call that function:

```
foo();
```

Instead of calling the function using its name, let's call it directly:

```
(function foo(){
    ...
})();
```

Since I don't use this function any where else, let's remove its name:

```
(function(){
    ...
})();
```

Want to pass a parameter to the function? Sure!

```
(function(something){
    ...
})(something);
```

Advantage of this? We have a scope!

```
(function(something){
    var bar = 5; // Can't access this outside the function
})(something);
```

This allows you to define stuff outside of the global scope.

Comment: thanks! answered all my questions and more :) appreciate that mate.

Comment: Vic has explained accurately.
If you want to explore more visit [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is an anonymous self-invoked function. So you are right, it calls itself straight away. If it had a name, that name would ONLY be visible inside those brackets `(..)`.

The dollar-sign functions are short-hand for [jQuery](http://jquery.com) calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that it a function that calls itself immediately, also called a *self executing function*.

The `$` is just shorthand using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

function(){} is declaring a function, while when we do

$(function() {}) it means we pass a function into another function $() as parameter, where this function will be executed by $() when the times met

it is much like

```
var a = function() { do something }
a();
```

will do something, in C# its like delegate, while in C++ it is like function pointer, in javascript it is made simple though where you can directly embed a function at the position where a parameter should be